# Spacing problem with \dim command

Tags: spacing, amsmath

If we use the `\dim` command from `amsmath`, shouldn't there be some space after dim?  For some reason, there is no space after dim if `\dim` is immediately followed by a `(`. However, enclosing the expression with opening and closing brackes in `{}' gives the desired output. Is this the expected behaviour?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\noindent \(\dim(U\cup W)\), \(\dim(U\cap W)\) \(\dim U\)\\% There is no space after dim
    \(\dim{(U\cap W)}\),% The output is as expected here.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is.````

Comment: Meaning this is the default/expected behaviour?

Comment: Yes. It is all due to how the spacing between different math atoms work.